# "Re-writing" the function `MemberQ`

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am trying to program the function `MemberQ` using less then possible functions pre defined by Mathematica. 
Until this now my code is:

```
meuMemberQ[f_,n_?NumericQ] /; (Length[Select[f, # == n &]] != 0):=True
meuMemberQ[f_,n_Symbol] /; (Length[Select[f, # == n &]] != 0) := True
meuMemberQ[f_,n_String] /; (Length[Select[f, # == n &]] != 0) := True
meuMemberQ[f_, n_] := False
```

There is a way to writing the same function but without using `Select` and `Length`?

Ps: It is just for exercise.

Comment: `meuMemberQ2[f_, n_] := Intersection[f, {n}] === {n}` or `meuMemberQ3[f_,n_]:= SubsetQ[f, {n}]`?

Comment: So... the ideia is not use others functions. In this case, not using `Intersection`

Comment: Hint: loop through the list elements and test each with `MatchQ`. You could use `AnyTrue` for convenience, or simply `Table` for a very basic implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recursive implementation:

```
meuMemberQ[{n_, y___}, n_] := True;
meuMemberQ[{x_, y___}, n_] := meuMemberQ[{y}, n];
meuMemberQ[{}, n_] := False;
```

This just cuts through the list step by step looking for an exact match of `n_`, and if it gets to an empty list it returns `False`.

It will run into the iteration limit eventually, but if you need to use it with such long lists, there are things that can be done (such as using `MemberQ`).

Answer (score 4):

A few alternatives:

```
ClearAll[meuMemberQ2, meuMemberQ3, meuMemberQ4]

meuMemberQ2[f_, n_] := Switch[n, Alternatives @@ f, True, _, False]
meuMemberQ3[f_, n_] := n /. {Alternatives@@f ->True, _:> False}

meuMemberQ4[{OrderlessPatternSequence[n_,___]}, n_] := True
meuMemberQ4[_,_]:=False
```